# How can we simplify and sort polynomial when taking input from the user and inserting it in the singly linked list

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

I have written a code that sorts the polynomial before/while inserting and tried simplifying the terms my code simplifies it but the problem comes if first 2 terms are different and last two terms have same exponent but my code doesn't simplify it just inserts it as it is. if anyone has an idea of how to simplify terms of polynomial before inserting do tell.

Comment: could you provide an example of your code and maybe some explanation about what "polynomial" is and how you store it?

Comment: using singly linked list  like it has a class term which consists of an exponent , coefficient, pointer next ;  class polynomial that has head and tail pointer plus a size pointer which is initially null user defines the size and enters coefficient and exponent for first term and we have to insert these terms in sorted order and simplified  in the list.

Comment: So could you provide an example of your code?

Comment: if ( head == NULL ||  head->Exponent < power) newterm = new Term (data,power,head) ;head = newterm ; else 
bool simplified = false ;Term *current = head ;
for ( ;current->next !=NULL && current->next->Exponent == power; current=current->next );if (current->Exponent == power){
current->Coefficient += data ;simplified = true ;}if (simplified != true ) for ( ;current->next !=NULL && current->next->Exponent > power; current=current->next );
newterm = new Term(data,power,current->next);
current ->next = newterm;

Comment: it is a bit long thats why it is posted in this shape

Comment: You actually can edit your question, so be free to paste code there and please format it according to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Ideally please make the effort to prepare your code sample to a [mre] form.

Comment: Code cannot be correctly formatted in comments. It has to be added in the question itself. I could do it for you, but as all formatting was lost in the comment and as I think that braces are missing, I cannot guess exactly what your real code is...